# Remove last element from SortedSet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, set

```
    for(RoomBookingDTO r : bb.getBooking().getRoomBookings()) {
        if(r.getLocalId() == bb.getCurrentRoomNumber()) {
            System.out.println("kom hit");
            bb.getBooking().getRoomBookings().remove(r);
        }
    }
```

When I try to print the `roomBookings` set before and after the remove method is run, the set contains exactly the same elements. Thus, `bb.getBooking().getRoomBookings().remove(r);` does not work. I use `java.util.SortedSet` implemented as a `java.util.TreeSet`. Any suggestions to why this is not working?

```
 RoomBookingDTO roomBooking = createRoomBooking(request);

    System.out.println("Before: " + bb.getBooking().getRoomBookings());
    bb.getBooking().getRoomBookings().add(roomBooking);
    System.out.println("Add: " + bb.getBooking().getRoomBookings());
    bb.getBooking().getRoomBookings().remove(roomBooking);
    System.out.println("After: " + bb.getBooking().getRoomBookings());
```

Comment: It's very suspicious to me that you're comparing the current room number to `getRoomBookings().size()` _and_ to a room booking ID. Does `RoomBookingDTO` correctly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

Comment: This is just a corner case. It's for handling user clicking backspace in a specific state. It isn't really important.

Comment: But does `RoomBookingDTO` correctly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`?

Comment: The code I added at the end works as expected. I guess that answers your question

Comment: Define "does not work". My guess is that you're getting a ConcurrentModificationException. And show your code instead of letting us guess. The compareTo() method of RoomBookingDTO is important.

Comment: I'm not getting any Exceptions. But I changed the way I handle the problem. This wasnt the way to go. Thanks anyway though